# Faster way to transfer image from android to web interface

Tags: javascript, java, android

What is the fastest transfer to send an image from the android app to a php web system?
I have tried sending the images to firebase storage and the url to realtime, and in the web interface I list these images to show them as a video. But this way the transitions are very slow.
So I ask what is the best way? Via retrofit? socket? Or another way of transfer that is faster than the one I showed you?
In short: I want to transmit the screen from android to a website, but the problem is that I capture several images one by one.

```
//TRANSFOMAR BITMAP EM ARRAY DE BYTES
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 5, baos);

                    byte[] dadosImagem = baos.toByteArray();

                    //criar nome unico de imagem
                    //String nomeImagem = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

                    StorageReference imagemRef = storageReference
                            .child("imagens")
                            .child("screenshot")
                            .child(idUser)
                            .child(IMAGES_PRODUCED+".jpeg");

                    //fazer upload da imagem
                    UploadTask uploadTask = imagemRef.putBytes(dadosImagem);

                    //se o upload foi feito com sucesso iremos inserir a URL da imagem no realtime
                    uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                            //em versoes anteriores do a gente recuperava assim taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                            //recuperar a url para inserir no realtime

                            imagemRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                                    //aqui temos a url da imagem
                                    String url = task.getResult().toString();

                                    Log.d("TAG", IMAGES_PRODUCED + url);

                                    //grava a url recuperada da imagem no realtime
                                    Imagem imagem = new Imagem();
                                    imagem.setUrl(url);
                                    imagem.setIdUsuario(idUser);
                                    imagem.salvarImagem();
```

sistema_web.php

Here on the web site with php and js I list the url of the images that were registered in firebase realtime.

```
<script type="text/javascript">                 

                firebase.database().ref('screenshot/'<?=$_GET['idUserFirebase']?>).on('value', (snapshot)=>{


                    snapshot.forEach(item => {

                        //console.log(snapshot.val());

                        //var img = document.querySelector("#screenshot");
                        //img.setAttribute('src', item.key);
                        let chave = item.key;
                        let dado = item.val();                      
                        console.log(chave, dado);

                        var img = document.querySelector("#screenshot");
                        img.setAttribute('src', dado);

                    });             
                    

                });               

            </script>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to stream the android screen to a website? Please clarify. Also mind the [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Yes, but in my app I capture several images, but I don't know the best way to transmit them.

Comment: I will adjust my question

Comment: So you are capturing images because your goal is to stream the screen? Because you don't know how to actually create a video stream, right? Again, mind the [*xy problem*](https://xyproblem.info/) --- also, I found this: https://github.com/fyhertz/spydroid-ipcamera

Comment: Thanks, I had already seen this api, but I don't know how to start implementing it in the code I already have. I found it difficult to implement, so I opted to send the images to firebase storage and then list them. It worked, but the transition of the images was slow.

Comment: I found this tutorial, but the person uses wowza in the middle to broadcast. https://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-streaming-live-camera-video-to-web-page/